# Start a service in android

Tags: android

I have this service class

```
package com.example.test43;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProximityService extends Service {

    private String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.example.proximityalert";
    private BroadcastReceiver locationReminderReceiver;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private PendingIntent proximityIntent;

 //@override
    public void onCreate() {
        locationReminderReceiver = new ProximityIntentReceiver();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Toast.makeText(this, "created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        double lat = 55.586568;
        double lng = 13.0459;
        float radius = 1000;
        long expiration = -1;

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        registerReceiver(locationReminderReceiver, filter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

        intent.putExtra("alert", "Test Zone");

        proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lng, radius, expiration, proximityIntent);

    }

// @override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(locationReminderReceiver);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d("receiver", e.toString());
        }

    }

// @override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

 //@override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



    public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

     //@suppressWarnings("deprecation")
     //@override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

            String place = arg1.getExtras().getString("alert");

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, arg1, 0);

            Notification notification = createNotification();

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, "Entering Proximity!", "You are approaching a " + place + " marker.", pendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

            locationManager.removeProximityAlert(proximityIntent);

        }

        private Notification createNotification() {
            Notification notification = new Notification();

            notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            return notification;
        }

    }
}
```

Here manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test43"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.ProximityService" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test43.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main

```
package com.example.test43;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, ProximityService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I want to know how do I start the service? I put a toast in the on create when the service starts just to know when starts but I don't see it. Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: have you declared your service in **Androidmanifest.xml**?

Comment: package names is different 
com.example.ProximityService
com.example.test43.MainActivity
is it ok you have two packages ?

Comment: You should refrain from using package name "com.example".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package name is incorrect when defining the service. Change you `Service` declaration in **Androidmanifest.xml** as below:

```
<service android:enabled="true"
      android:name="com.example.test43.ProximityService" />
```